# Amateur Text Editor Malfunctioning

Tags: python, for-loop, text-editor

My brother and I are creating a simple text editor that changes entries to pig latin using Python. Code below:

```
our_word = ("cat")
vowels = ("a","e","i","o","u")
#remember I have to compare variables not strings
way = "way"
for i in range(len(our_word)):
    for j in range (len(vowels)):
        #checking if there is any vowel present
        if our_word[i] == vowels[j]:
            # if there were to be any vowels our_word[i] wil now be changed with way
            #.replace is our function the dot is what notates this in the python library
            our_word = our_word.replace(our_word[i], way)
print(our_word)
```

Right now we're testing the word 'cat' but the program when run returns the following:

```
/Users/x/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/venv/bin/python /Users/x/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/main.py
cwwayyt

Process finished with exit code 0
```

We're not sure why there is a double 'w' and a double 'y'. It seems the word 'cat' is edited once to 'cwayt' and then a second time to 'cwwayyt'.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: The first time you change c[a]t - > c[way]t, the second time it's cw[a]yt -> cw[way]yt.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from the fact that on the next iteration of `for` loop after doing the substitution, you are looking at the next position, which is part of the `way` that you just substituted into place.  Instead, you need to skip past this.  You would also experience another problem, that it only loops up to the original length, rather than the new increased length.  You are probably better in this situation to use a `while` loop with an index variable that you can manipulate to point to the correct place as needed.  For example:

```
our_word = "cat"
vowels = "aeiou"
way = "way"
i = 0
while i < len(our_word):
    if our_word[i] in vowels:
        our_word = our_word[:i] + way + our_word[i + 1:]
        i += len(way)  # <=== if you made a substitution, skip over the bit
                       #      that you just substituted in place
    else:
        i += 1  # <=== if you didn't make any substitution 
                #       just go to the next position next time
        
print(our_word)
```